# Find max per id after counting and grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table I have bus rides taken in different networks - each record represents one ride.

My goal is to find the max number of rides taken in a day in  **each network**  and the day that the max number of rides occurred - which requires first counting the number of rides per day in each network and then taking the max count per network - in the end I will have three columns -

`YMD` - `max_count`- `network_id`

I have tried to use the query below but I am not sure where or how to include the `max()` function.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (network_id)
           network_id, count(*), to_char(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as YMD
    FROM   routes
    ORDER  BY network_id, count DESC, YMD;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an aggregate query to count the number of rides a day, and then a windowing `rank` call to find the date with the most rides:

```
SELECT network_id, cnt, ymd
FROM   (SELECT network_id, 
               ymd,
               cnt, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY network_id ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rk
        FROM   (SELECT network_id, 
                       TO_CHAR(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ymd, 
                       COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM   routes
                GROUP BY network_id, TO_CHAR(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
               ) t
       ) s
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: thanks, but this throws the error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t"`

Comment: @the_darkside I was missing a `)` there, thanks. Edited my answer to fix the issue.